# I have a dataframe with shape (601, 2522). I want the indexing to start from the second row of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, ordereddictionary, ordereddict

Change the indexing to start from the second row of the dataframe. Because, this dataframe will be transformed into an Ordereddict, where I will use the first row of the element as labels for my dataset.

-Tried multiindexing in the dataframe, but what happend is when I change to ordereddict, the dict has two keys:

OrderedDict([('0',  'shot')
              0      1577
              1      1577])

I want only one key and the remaining to be values, but 'shot' should not be indexed as this will be the column name for the data

Currently the ordereddict looks like this:
OrderedDict([('0', 0      shot
              1      1577
              2      1577
              3      2106
              4      2106
              5      1875)]
And I want it like this:

OrderedDict([('0',   shot
              0      1577
              1      1577
              2      2106
              3      2106
              4      1875)]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like the code below:

```
data = np.loadtxt("path to file", delimiter = ',', dtype = 'str')
csv_data = data[1:,0:2] #[start row:end row, start col:end col]
```

tell me if this helps solve your problem?

Comment: The indexing starts from 0, and if you put 1 in the row indexing it should start from the second row.

Comment: when I change array to dataframe again, the indexing starts from 0 again. Is there a way to convert array to orderreddict?